# Need clarification on a Taylor polynomial question

Tags: taylor-expansion

$$f(x) = 5 \ln(x)-x$$

second Taylor polynomial centered around $b=1$ is $-1 + 4(x-1) - (5/2)(x-1)^2$

let $a$ be a real number : $0 < a < 1$

let $J$ be closed interval $[1-a, 1+a]$

find upper bound for the error $|f(x)-T_2(x)|$ on interval $J$

answer in terms of a

so i got to the point where i have $|f(x)-T_2(x)| <= (10/6)(x-1)^3$ however the answer is

$(5/3)(a/(1-a))^3$

How did the $a/(1-a)$ get there? If i sub in for the max $x$ which would be $1 + a$, then i 
would get $(5/3)(a)^3$. Why is it divided by $(1-a)$?

Comment: Is that exactly how the problem is specified?

Comment: It's a multipart question the 1st part was to find the 2nd taylor polynomial and part b of the question is :  Let
a be a real number such that 0< a <1 and let J be the closed interval [1-a, 1+a]. Use quadratic app. error bound to find upper bound for the error |f(x)-T_2(x)| on the interval J. (Your answer will be in terms of a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given:

$$f(x) = 5 \ln(x) - x$$

The second Taylor polynomial centered around $b=1$ is given by:

$$T_2(x) = -\frac{1}{2} 5 (x-1)^2+4 (x-1)-1$$

We are told to let $a$ be a real number such that $0 \lt a \lt 1$ and let $J$ be the closed interval $[1 −a, 1 +a]$.

We are then asked to use the Quadratic Approximation Error Bound to find an upper bound for the error $|f(x) − T_2(x)|$ on the interval $J$.

The error term is given by:

$$R_{n+1} = \dfrac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}(x-b)^{n+1} \le \dfrac{M}{(n+1)!}(x-b)^{n+1}$$

We have $b=1, n= 2$, and have to find the max error for two items, thus:

$$\dfrac{d^3}{dx^3} (5 \ln(x)-x) = \dfrac{10}{x^3}$$

So the maximum of $f^{(3)}(x)$ is given by:

$$\displaystyle \max_{J} \left|f'''(x)\right| = \max_{ 1-a \le x \le 1+a} \left|\dfrac{10}{x^3}\right|$$

The max occurs at the left endpoint because $0 \lt a \lt 1$, so the maximum is given by:

$$\dfrac{10}{(1-a)^3}$$

Next, we have to repeat this and find the maximum of $(x-1)^3$. In this case, the maximum occurs at the rightmost endpoint, hence the maximum is:

$$((1+a) - 1)^3 = a^3$$

Putting this together yields:

$$\left|f(x)-T_2(x)\right| = R_{3} = \dfrac{f^{(3)}(c)}{3!}(x-1)^{3} \le \dfrac{M}{3!}(x-1)^{3} = \dfrac{10}{3!(1-a)^3}a^3 = \dfrac{5}{3} \left(\dfrac {a}{1-a}\right)^3$$